# How can I detect a user tap outside the list item?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I want to build a function that allow user to swipe the list item to set an item become archived to Delete. When user tap outside the list item, the product will be delete.

In Sencha Touch how to detect user tap outside the selected list item in List ?

Comment: Did you checked is there a blur event?

Answer (score 1):

Please help me to understand what you want to do. Is this correct:

I want to add a swipe-gesture to listitems. The swipe will open a new underlying object, either to archive or delete the item. 
How can I grab the tap outside the list, but inside the tapped area?

---

Based on this I would add functionality on the object below on the swipe gesture. At after closing the item, I would unset the listener.

You can add the tap event to any element you like like this:

container is a new Ext.Container

```
container.element.on('tap', function(btn){doSomething})
```

If you need to fetch an area outside the swiped part , there are 3 possible events on the list you need to listen to:

- scroll (list of mails)
- itemtap (a different item, which opens another mail)
- swipe (a different item to also delete another mail)

Deleting item in Gmail happends directly on swiping. You can restore it and archive it on a second action. So listen to these three events if there is a deletion on the go on the events.

Comment: Your above code is right. But It just assiged to one/some element. I want it assiged to all elment, except the swiped list item.

I want to make an function like Gmail for Android. You swipe an item to archive to delete it. And when user tap outside the item, Gmail will delete the swiped item.

Comment: I will look later into Gmail at a friend. Will post more later.

Comment: I added to my answer at the end.

Comment: First. Many thanks you to help  me :)
With above event is also make somewhat. But its't slove the problem. I need one more event ( this will slove my question ). How to detect user tap/double-tap.... outside the list. Or another hand is how to detect the list is lost-focus.

Comment: You could always add Ext.Viewport.element.on('tap', function(arguments){} and get from the arguments what you need to know.